# building a fast redirect server

Tags: php, node.js, redis, node-redis

I want to create a tracking platform but am in need of some advice. What it has to do is the following:

- Someone visits a link e.g. http://click.track.com/redirect?campaign=1&partnet_id=2
- When visiting this link a user get's redirect to e.g. http://google.com/?xx=xx

I'm going to use redis since it's really fast and considering the following two options since I have the knowledge to build it in that way.

- PHP
- NodeJS

I'm thinking that NodeJS is going to be faster but would like to know opinions of other people. Maybe I just have to learn something else to make it work even better :)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build an affiliate tracking program - i would recommend NOT writing it yourself - and using or paying for proven software - you will find this is MUCH more complicated than you expect

Comment: Hi Dan, that's correct. I'm not going to be the only person working on it as you can imagine. Building it all alone will take way too much time. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: looks like you gave the right mindset with NODE over php - in terms of simple redirects and url rewriting - that is the better way to go - plus if you open up some sort of API - pretty much EVERYONE expects to work with JSON so you are already set up in the best env for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into `HAPI` server - this is a BATTLE tested node server that gives you SO many options. `Express` may work too but i put my trust in the `HAPI` server stack. Plus they have alot of great add ons and plugins.

https://hapijs.com/

Redis is also a great key value store as well - Look into CASSANDRA too

http://cassandra.apache.org/

https://redis.io/

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.Will definetly look into cassande and hapijs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a good hosting service provider like digitalocean, amazon cloud etc. for faster redirection. PHP or NodeJS it doesn't matter much when you have a faster hosting.

Comment: Yes offcourse the hosting needs to be good. But I believe the benchmarks for nodejs where are a lot faster than using php.